# How can I find whether the function f is differentiable and/or continuous?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

The function that I have is:

$$f(x)= \begin{cases}x^2 + 1 & \text{if } x \leq 0 \text{, and } \\ x^3 + 1 & \text{if } x > 0 \; .\end{cases}$$

For part a I have to find that f is differentiable at $x=0$ using the limit definition of the derivative.
Right now I found the limits using

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

and for the first equation I got

$$\lim_{h \to 0} 2x+h$$

and for the second equation I got

$$\lim_{h \to 0} 3x^2+3xh+h^2$$

would that be the correct way to do part a? Also, what would I do to prove that it is differentiable?

And for part b, I have to show that the derivative function f prime is continuous at $x=0$ but not differentiable at $x=0$, and for that I got 2 for the first equation and $9x^2$ for the second. I took both equations from part a and substituted 0 for h. From that, I took the derivative I got from the first equation, 2x, and the second equation, 3x^3. From that I took the derivative of those and got 2 and 9x^2 respectively.

How can I fix what I have? Thank you!

Comment: If I saw it correctly, the first part with x=0 is correct, because you examined that the left and right limit both exist near 0 and are the same. What have you tried for the second part yet?

Comment: For the second part I took the derivative of the answers I got when I substituted h for 0

Answer (score 1):

As you have found, the right and left *derivative* limits are equal at $x=0$.

Now you can say that $$f'(x) = \begin{cases}2x, & x\le0 \\ 3x^2, & x > 0 \end{cases}$$
Obviously $$\lim_{x\to0^-}f'(x) = \lim_{x\to0^+}f'(x) = 0$$
Hence $f'(x)$ is continuous.
$$f''(x^-) = \lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{2x - 0}{x} = 2 \\ f''(x^+) = \lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{3x^2 - 0}{x} = 0$$
Hence $f'(x)$ is not differentiable.

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question? I think the OP means the continuity of the derivative function, not the function $f$.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I got that wrong. Will edit. @Acc-lab

Comment: Don't forget the part proving that $f''(x)$ does not exists. I'll solve the question by left/right derivatives does not equal to each other.

Comment: This is the correct answer. since the left/right limit of $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ does not equal to each other, the limit does not exists, and hence it's not differentiable by the definition.